# Can I use Quantum lab during IBM Quantum certification exam?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

Hello I am about to take the IBM Quantum Qiskit dev exam. I don't know if I can use the quantum lab (Qiskit) during the exam. Does anyone know?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not suited for SE

Answer (score 0):

no you can't. you take the exam on an app that closes all other applications when launched.

Comment: But what stopped people from using their other devices to access quantum lab or just qiskit from their local machine?

Comment: i think they monitor the candidate's movements from the webcam.